# Potential Difference between 2 points in a curcuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, charge, potential, capacitance

3 Cells and 3 capacitors are connected as shown in the diagram. What is the potential difference between points A and B ? What are the final charges on each of the plates of the Capacitor ?
Does the sum of charges on the right plates of all the capacitors add upto 0 ? And can the potential difference between the 2 points be calculated without using Kirchoff's Laws ?

[image: Curcuit Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use Kirchoff's law to get the answer.

<strike>How can some of positive numbers be zero? No, the sum of all charges will be zero while that of positive plate will be finite.</strike>

Now the net sum would be zero since charge is conserved on the system having all the right plates.

Use Kirchoff's Loop Law and Kirchoff's current law to find charges and potential.

Comment: I edited the question regarding charge on positive plates. Now, what would the sum be ?

Comment: @AritraDas Made an edit.